# Kotlin hashmap "expecting member declaration"

Tags: android, kotlin

```
class Config() {
var items = HashMap<String, Int>()
items.put("D", 1000)
items["A"] = 10
items["B"] = 20
items["C"] = 30
```

}

I think there is no problem, But the error happend  "expecting member declaration"
How can I dodge that error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can't just fill in hashMap in the middle of the class. Do it in init or function

```
class Config{

    private val items = HashMap<String, Int>()

    fun putInfo(){
        items["A"] = 1000
        items["B"] = 500
        items["C"] = 200
        //...
    }

}
```

or

```
class Config{

    private lateinit var items: HashMap<String, Int>

    init {
        items = HashMap<String, Int>()
        items["A"] = 1000
        items["B"] = 500
        items["C"] = 200
        //...
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class Config {
lateinit var items: HashMap<String, Int>
init {
    items.put("D", 1000)
    items["A"] = 10
    items["B"] = 20
    items["C"] = 30
}}
```